# How to save users data in a Tiered application (separated dbcontext for identity server and application/module)

Tags: abp

I have a question regarding an application that I am developing, I try to implement a Kanban solution.

I have separated the IdentityServer (Users, Roles, etc), from the module/app that I am implementing. (Tiered)

I would like to know how I should do to have user data in the module/app.
I mean, it should have the "duplicate" users table or from the module/app can refer to the context of the identityServer database...

I am a bit lost...

For trying to give an example.

IdentityDbContext { Users, Roles, etc }

ApplicationDbContext { Board, Columns, Tags, Cards, CardUser, ¿User? }

In CardUser I would like to have the users related to Card (an N-M relationship).
But I don't know if I should create an entity/DbSet in the ApplicationDbContext or just save the UserId and then for each UserId query data to db or do call to api to the IdentityServer.

I think it's hard for me to explain myself, I'm sorry if it doesn't make sense, I appreciate any kind of help/comment.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per best practices, aggregate root can be referenced by its id, but it is recommended not to reference it with the navigation property.

We have implemented a similar case for EventHub. You can see how we implemented it from the links below.

https://github.com/abpframework/eventhub/blob/e19c32731655df8c78d082a84cb336263c5f081a/src/EventHub.Domain/Events/Speaker.cs#L10

https://github.com/abpframework/eventhub/blob/e19c32731655df8c78d082a84cb336263c5f081a/src/EventHub.Application/Events/EventAppService.cs#L366

---

You can try to create an Event to better understand the requirements of EventHub.

https://www.openeventhub.com/

Comment: I really appreciate your comment, thank you very much @berkansasmaz


In the end I thought that the best thing is to just save the UserId and then have an AppService that obtains the user information through a REST API call, and then do Join for show the data in the view. Thanks for the links, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: After reviewing quickly (perhaps I have not seen it well), I think that in the EventHub sample application there is only one DbContext, the EventHubDbContext that replaces the IdentityDbContext.

The problem I have is that I have two independent applications, the AuthServer (IdentityServerHost) and the application that I am developing PlanningApp.

Each one has its own DbContext and its own independent databases.

It seems to me that the example you propose is not similar...

Comment: I understand, yes, unfortunately, I misunderstood your question, having independent databases complicates your question. Because the problem has many solutions. For example, one of them is to make an API call as you said, but this has its disadvantages.

Comment: Another quick solution that comes to my mind is to keep the user's data you need in the other db, this method is used a lot in the microservice world, but it brings up other problems you have to deal with. As an example, we can give the Ordering service of eShopOnAbp(https://www.eshoponabp.com/). There, the necessary information for the ordering service of the purchaser is kept in each order. https://github.com/abpframework/eShopOnAbp/blob/main/services/ordering/src/EShopOnAbp.OrderingService.Domain/Orders/Buyer.cs

Comment: Thanks @berkansasmaz, I try to do like eshoponabp or do a API call or DB querry... for now I only save the userId...